# How can I mount a winch to a steel pole?

Tags: bolts, threading, winch

In order to raise -- and tighten -- a volleyball net every evening, we've attached a [winch](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B096ZGNGGY/) to one of the poles. The attachment is by two bolts going into the existing threaded holes in the pole.

It works, but the bolts aren't thick and, because the winch goes side-to-side a little, when the net is raised or taken down, I am afraid, they might snap eventually.

As you can see in the picture, the implement has two other holes -- plastic zip-ties are running through them now -- which could be used with some sort of U-bolt. Except a straight U-bolt will not work, because the pole's diameter is 3″, whereas the distance between holes is under 2″.

Hence my question about some sort of Ω-bolt (or Ʊ-bolt?) -- which would "hug" the 3-inch pole, but with the threaded ends going into the holes available? Do such things exist -- and, if so, what are they called?

Any other suggestions? I thought of using steel hose-clamps -- but they all tend to be wider, than our holes. And not as hard as a bolt would be, anyway -- just a little better than the plastic zip-ties...

[image: winch attached to pole]

Comment: Yes, though we call them U-bolts.  U-bolt around the pole with the threaded ends going through the holes where the zip tie is, just what you described.

Comment: Yes, @SteveSh, that's what I wanted -- but the regular (straight) U-bolt will not fit, because the holes are closer apart, than the pole's diameter. The U-bolt needs to narrow -- like Ω... The U-bolts I've seen are all too hard to bend so much -- from 3" down to 1.5"...

Comment: Look up (Google) "antenna mast mount" for some ideas. (can't post pictures in a comment).

Comment: Mm, I don't see anything suitable -- could you post a link here?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/PRO-SIGNAL-33-12256-Antenna-Clamp/dp/B07NVJ1C67.  I was thinking it might provide a flat surface for the cable winch to sit on.  Don't use the bolts; just the serrated part.

Comment: I think, I see, what you mean... Maybe, that will work -- just to keep it from moving.

Comment: That antenna mast clamp from @SteveSh is a simpler and cheaper version of what I posted in my answer.  IDK if it is strong enough but for the price it's worth a try.  It looks like it would allow you to ALSO use the existing bolt all the way through the pole for added strength.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a conduit hanger.

It goes around the pole, tighten the nut and bolt that's on the left side in Pic. This will clamp the hanger onto the pipe.

On the right side, I added a small bolt, this is where you would secure the winch to the hanger/pole.

[image: conduit hanger]
[image: conduit hanger on pipe.]

** Edit **
You could use a piece of kindorf with a kindorf strap...

Strap around pipe, kindorf other side of pipe and attach winch to kindorf. If you don't have small fingers, attach winch to kindorf first. For added strength from the strap sliding around the pole, you can screw through the strap into the pipe.

They have different types of kindorf, thick/thin, holes or slots.

Everything I mentioned can be found in a hardware store or big box store.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: The only potential drawback I see to this is that the torque of using the winch _could_ bend the stand-off portion of the bracket. Still got my +1.

Comment: Possible, let me grab a stronger hanger and add to my post.

Comment: Ah, the new ones do seem stronger, than the zip-ties... But this also creates sharp edges on the other  -- court- -- side of the pole, for a player to injure himself :(

Comment: Sharp edges are fixable with a file or grinder or even wrapped in rubber or pipe insulation after rounding edges.

Comment: Not sure, if I can hook these through the existing holes in the winch, though... They are round -- made for bolts (or screws)... Ideally, it'd be something like [this](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B08X2CPBH5/) -- but with threads rather than "ears" at both ends... A curved U-bolt.

Comment: You would attach the winch to the kindorf, cut down to the width of the winch. Using this setup will give more backing and stability to the winch.

Answer (score 2):

**A U-bolt could pretty easily be bent to suit.** Squeeze it together after it's on the pole, then wrap it with some wire. Now take a wrench, pliers, or bit of pipe and bend the legs back to parallel. An extra deep U-bolt might make this all easier, and you may need to trim the ends after shaping, for clearance.

This would also serve to stabilize it laterally, as the legs would grab the winch base at the outer ends of the mounting slot (they'll be pulled outward by the tension from the wider pole). Super simple and rock solid, especially if there's another slot at the bottom.

Comment: If you use U bolts, use a spacing bar to keep the legs apart (as your winch has long holes that will not do that) and place nuts and washers on *both sides* of the winch so it won't butt against the pole and want to be bent around it by its mounting.

Comment: The legs of the bolt will naturally be drawn apart due to the spread caused by the pole. There's no need for a spacer. That winch housing is robust enough that deformation isn't a concern short of going absolutely ape on the nuts.

Comment: U-Bolt, +1. But bending it might be tough. Use a ~6" stick of 1/4" thick steel to **make bracket 'ears'**, with four holes drilled into it. Two for the u-bolt and two to mount it to the pulley. Quantity two. (no washers or nuts necessary on the inside with 1/4" steel. If it starts to bend stop tightening.)

Comment: That seems like a different answer, Mazura.

Answer (score 1):

#### Strong and Firm

This is a pole bracket for a security camera.  Buy the right size for your pole, so the gap between the ends of the wings is about half the pole diameter (or less).   Search for "security camera pole bracket".  They are not expensive.

[image: pole bracket]

Secure it to the pole with two or three metal hose clamps.

[image: hose clamps]

The resulting strength of the attachment to the pole is incredible, and the large face with versatile holes allows you to attach your crank very securely also.

Here I have two of them attached to a 4 inch pole in my garage.  I'm using them with cleats not winches because I'm using block and tackle in my garage, and I'm only using one hose clamp because I don't have the kind of stresses that a winch would apply.

[image: Two pole mounts mounted on a pole]

I think this is more suitable than brackets that are mainly intended to keep pipes from falling off walls.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at these, but I don't think, they are strong enough for the sideways stresses of cranking -- by an enthusiastic volleyballer eager to start playing :)

Comment: These are much, much stronger than anything else that has been suggested here and 10,000,000 times stronger than your wire ties.  Use two hose clamps, this spreads the load vertically.  Rotationally around the pole, the edges of the mounting bite into the pole.

Comment: We're not using wire ties. We're using bolts -- because the pole already had them (something else used to be attached to it years ago). Did you mean the plastic zip-ties pictured? Those aren't adding much, I agree...